# WSO2 SSO Global Logout not working when applcations are put behind Proxy

Tags: wso2

Problem Statement: -
WSO2 Global Logout not working because of Firewall Rules.

Architecture Description:- 
I have two applications running on :-  http://HostName1:Port1/APP-A and  http://HostName2:Port2/APP-B and both application are running inside the company network.

Both Application Put behind the Apache Proxy  https://proxy.com/APP-A, https://proxy.com/APP-B.

At WSO2 UI, I have to configure the Enable Single Logout (SLO Response URL) directly with hostnames http://HostName1:Port1/APP-A/logout and http://HostName2:Port2/APP-B/logout .

Use Case:- 
User has logged in both  application App-A and App-B.

If User logout from APP-A, WSO2 calls SLO Response URL through Browser [i.e. SendRedirect] for App-A and directly calls SLO API for App-B.

User gets successfully logged out of APP-B, because WSO2 is connecting directly to the SLO API (behind the proxy). But  logout for APP-A fails because  WOS2 tries to redirect the browser to URL http://HostName1:Port1/app1/logout which is not exposed externally.

We need to configure WSO2 to connect directly to the SLO API of caller application (APP-A in this case) behind the proxy.

Could you please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Edit repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml and add proxyName and proxyPort to the Connector.

This change should be enough. If it still doesn't work, you should check HostName/ MgtHostName in carbon.xml file. Might be also useful to change ProxyContextPath there.